# buying a virtual Number on Twilio from a test account

Tags: twilio

We requested for a virtual number in twilio and got this response but we don't know how to buy this number as there is still no number showing on the options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The suggestion from the team there is to use an [alphanumeric sender ID](https://twiliodoer.secure.force.com/SenderId) to send your messages. In the UAE you need to pre-register these sender IDs.

To do so, head to [this form](https://twiliodoer.secure.force.com/SenderId) and fill in your details.

Comment: hi Evangelist! Can we also use this alphanumeric Sender ID in WhatsApp? We are actually interested in using Twilio on mainly on WhatsApp only for our customer service team. Do you have any suggestions and other options for us?

Comment: You can't use an alphanumeric sender ID in WhatsApp, no. But, the country of origin of a number doesn't matter as much on WhatsApp as there are no charges for users to send to WhatsApp numbers anywhere in the world. So, you can use a number from another country. There are [some other options for WhatsApp numbers that you can read about here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052171393-Can-I-activate-my-own-phone-number-for-WhatsApp-on-Twilio-).